# How to read and mark an entry as read using django REST framework?

Tags: django, rest

I would like to update an entry as soon as it has been read.
For the following model

```
    class BlogEntry(models.Model):
        read = models.BooleanField()
        text = models.TextField(null=False, null=True)
```

I would like to do a webcall eg. http://hostname/blogs/xx/ but before returning the JSON the entry has to be marked as read.

What is the appropriate way of doing this I can think of many hacks but there has to be a proper way?

Comment: You mean to set that boolean flag the first time anyone ever requests the data?

Comment: I could also describe this problem as "How to pop an entry from a database using django-rest framework".